# Will my new RAM will fit my motherboard?

Tags: memory, motherboard, ddr2

I am about to purchase **2x4GB sticks** of **Komputerbay DDR2 non-ECC 240 pin RAM** (http://amzn.to/1gXf65X) and I wanted to make sure that it would fit my [ASRock N68C-GS4 FX Motherboard](http://www.asrock.com/mb/NVIDIA/N68C-GS4%20FX/?cat=Specifications), as I have been unsuccessful before.

Comment: Your motherboard manufacturer should provide documentation as to the size and types of memory it will accept.

Comment: Have you thought about buying your memory from Crucial (http://uk.crucial.com/gbr/en)? Sorry I don't know if you have a system or are building from scratch

Comment: As mrowevr suggested, look in your motherboard manual. It will have a page that lists the compatible ram manufacturers and timings that work.

Comment: This depends on what type of RAM you have installed, whether you want to keep it and what exactly your CPU is.

Comment: Judging from your previous questions, it looks like you finally got it right. This is non-ECC and 240-pin RAM for desktops. It should be compatible with motherboards that support DDR2 RAM. Check the Amazon reviews for anecdotal information from other purchasers, it looks like it worked for just about everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Will it **fit**? Yes.

Will it **work**? Depends on your processor.